# Long boot time due to "waiting for network configuration" - but network is configured statically

Tags: boot, networking, init, network-bridge, ppp

My system has a statically configured network that is fully functional. However, booting needs a long time due to "Waiting for network configuration" messsages.

What can be the cause for this?

I mitigated the impact by changing the delays in /etc/init/failsafe.conf , but I want to understand the problem.

The system had this behaviour after a fresh install (13.10) and kept it after update (14.04).

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth1 inet manual
iface wlan0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 up
address 192.168.133.7
netmask 255.255.255.0
bridge_ports eth0 wlan0
bridge_fd 5
bridge_stp no

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
post-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
provider dsl-provider
```

In syslog I can see that network is started fast (including the bridge and ppp), but services depending on it are started later (e.g. dnsmasq)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the sleep time in /etc/init/failsafe.conf. Use the below commands to change the time,

```
mount -o remount,rw / 

sudo nano /etc/init/failsafe.conf
```

Save and then reboot the machine. Hope this helps.

Comment: "I mitigated the impact by changing the delays in /etc/init/failsafe.conf , but I want to understand the problem."

Comment: It might be due to the time change in sleep calls.